# CustomInfoWindow Error

Tags: ios

Hi I am trying to create a custom info window for GMS marker in Swift 3. I have created a sub UI View in my view controller and called it CustomInfoWindow. I have then created a new Swift File with class CustomInfoWindow as UIView to connect the label in my custom info window. I will be pasting my code in the bottom. The problem is a sigabrt error but more specifically 
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'CustomInfoWindow''
Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class ViewTwo: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: .zero, camera: camera)
        mapView.delegate = self
        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        self.view = mapView

        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20)
        marker.title = "Sydney"
        marker.isTappable = true
        marker.map = mapView

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {
        let infoWindow = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomInfoWindow", owner: self.view, options: nil)!.first! as! CustomInfoWindow
        infoWindow.title.text = marker.title
        return infoWindow
    }

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Please Help.

Comment: have you assigned the custom class to the nib in the storyboard? Most of the times, we forget to assign the custom class to controllers.

Comment: Did you try it this way? Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomInfoWindow", owner: nil, options: nil)?.first as! CustomInfoWindow

Comment: Hi Dark Innoncence I already created a custom UI View Class and Aaqib I tried but still showing errors